# Condition for stationary density matrix

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, density-operator, time-evolution

I have a question about section 5 in *'Statistical mechanics'* (Pathria).

According this book, the density matrix (operator) should satisfy the following identity, which describes the time evolution of density matrix:
$$i\hbar \dot{\hat{\rho}} =\left[\hat H,\hat \rho \right]$$
After this equation, the book says, if the density matrix is stationary ($\dot{\hat \rho}=0$),

1. density matrix operator should commute with Hamiltonian and
2. Hamiltonian has no time dependence.

I think that the condition is too strong. Can we show that (1) & (2) is 'necessary and sufficient condition' for stationary condition of density matrix?
That is, the stationary condition ($\dot{\hat \rho}=0$) always leads to (1)&(2)?

Comment: I updated the last line at the main post, my question was: the stationary condition always leads to (1)&(2)?

Comment: I don't think that if $\rho$ commutes with $H(t)$ then $H$ is time-independent. Indeed, if $\rho(t)=\mathbb I/d = \rho(t_0)$ where $d:=\mathrm{dim}\,h$, where $h$ is the (finite-dimensonal, complex) Hilbert space in question, then $\rho$ commutes with every operator and in particular with $H(t)$, whatever this then may be. However, *if* the equation in the question holds, then if $\dot \rho =0$, it follows that $[\rho,H(t)]=0$ for all $t$. Conversely, if $\rho$ commutes with $H(t)$ at all times, then $\dot \rho =0$.

Comment: [Related if not duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225459/time-dependence-of-density-operator-in-quantum-statistical-mechanics)

Comment: I think so, too. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the book is correct. Given that $i\hbar \partial_t{\hat{\rho}} =\left[\hat H,\hat \rho \right]$ and $\partial_t{\hat{\rho}} =0$, we have:

1. $\left[\hat H,\hat \rho \right]=0$ so the Hamiltonian and the density matrix commute.
2. One sufficient condition to ensure the commutation is that the density is a functional of the Hamiltonian, $\rho=\rho[\hat H]$.
3. Then you can check by the chain rule that $\partial_t{\hat{\rho}[\hat H]} =0$ implies that $\partial_t\hat H =0$ (this is, the Hamiltonian does not depend explicitly on time).

Comment: But your condition $2.$ is an extra assumption, no? See for example my comment under the question.

Comment: @TobiasFünke, I am not sure, but wouldn't $\left[\hat H,\hat \rho \right]=0$ imply that $\rho$ is a functional of $\hat H$? Just as any other relation $f(\hat H,\hat \rho)=0$ would. I am more used to working with classical SM, where this kind of reasoning is standard in Liouville's theorem. Sorry, I don't get your example in the comment section.

Comment: I don't understand that reasoning at all. For example, $[X,S_z]=0$ - does this imply that $X$ a function(al) of $S_z$?! Where by an abuse of notation I mean $X\sim X\otimes  \mathbb I_{\mathbb C^2}$ and $S_z \sim \mathbb I_{L^2} \otimes S_z$ on the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb R)\otimes \mathbb C^2$. Or even easier: on $L^2(\mathbb R^2)$ we have $[X,P_y]=0$; is $X$ a functional of $P_y$? I don't see it, but of course I can be very wrong here, so I really mean it as a question.

Comment: Regarding the example/comment under the question. With $\rho(t_0)=\mathbb I/d$ the initial value problem is solved by $\rho(t)=\rho(t_0)$ for all $t$ (easy to check). Now this does not, in any way, put a constraint on $H(t)$. In particular, it can be time-dependent. So your argument does not work here, as far as I can see.

Comment: Regarding our discussion, cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374772/when-are-two-commuting-linear-operators-functions-of-each-other).

Comment: I get your point now. I am confused because in classical SM you will have the Poisson bracket $\{H,\rho]=0$ instead of the commutator. In that case, you can say that $\rho$ is a constant of movement; therefore, it has to be a function of conserved quantities.  But in order to state that energy is conserved one must have a Hamiltonian that doesn't depend explicitly on time! So, the fact that the Hamiltonian has no time dependence is needed to say that $\rho=\rho[H]$. So in classical systems, my second point is not general, and my third point is instead a given than a deduction.

Comment: Just FYI (and possible other future readers of this question): [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/738080/are-commuting-operators-a-function-of-the-other) is a recent PSE question which complements the math SE post I linked some comments above.